# Why does Octave show me contents after csvread?

Tags: octave

When I run the ".m" file from within Octave in cygwin, I get the contents of "data" in the terminal window - why?

It is the same as if I had typed "data".

```
function test2uf
warning("off","Octave:broadcast");
debug_on_warning(1);
debug_on_error(1);
data=csvread('TestData.csv',1,1)

%other stuff

endfunction
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a semi-colon after that line it will suppress the display of the `data` variable that you just populated

```
data=csvread('TestData.csv',1,1);
```

Comment: Real newbie mistake - thank you

Comment: @ManInMoon No problem

Comment: @ManInMoon the `;` suppresses output to the command prompt which can significantly speed up your code. I would recommend it as the default for every line.